# How to know the index of clicked image in android?

Tags: android

I am new in android. I have an array of images:

```
private int[] textureArrayWin = {
  R.drawable.basketball,
  R.drawable.soccer         
};
```

Try to dynamically add them to my view:

```
for(int i=0; i < textureArrayWin.length; i++){      
    Log.v("asd", "index=" + i);
    ImageView tv = new ImageView(this);     
    tv.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    tv.setImageResource(textureArrayWin[i]);
    tv.setAdjustViewBounds(true);           
    tv.setMaxHeight(20);
    tv.setMaxWidth(20);
    myLayout.addView(tv);
```

}

But don't know how:

1. Fit them by "setMaxHeight", they are still big
2. How to know index of clicked image in array or to receive some id of image which allow to know the unique id of image in my layout. In javascript, for example, I can do it by adding attr to element and in handler receive attribute by "this.getAttribute(someAttr)"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Id attribute to identify the views.

Assign a Id to each view by:

```
myView.setId(<some Integer value here>);
```

You can later refer to same view by:

```
 View v =  findViewById(<same Integer value here>);
```